# Config settings for S3 sink connector

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I am new to S3 sink connector, I am trying to setup s3 connector for my project.
I have few doubts:

- What is the use of **flush.size** in config? what if I give the very large number(2147483647) for it, then how would it work?
- rotate.interval.ms - How does this work if I give its value as 1 hour ?
- rotate.schedule.interval.ms - If I use this setting would I get duplicate records?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

flush size determines an upper bound on the number of records you expect in files; if you set it large, then you'll either run out of memory/disk space on the Connect workers, or you'll end up one large file per partition or rotation interval

The two settings operate on different intervals, and shouldn't be combined. If you rotate every hour, you should expect the records (who's buffer size would be less than the flush size at that time) to be flushed that often

For next question, from documentation

> setting rotate.schedule.interval.ms is nondeterministic and will invalidate exactly-once guarantees

Comment: I have few questions here:

 1. I have 10 topics to read data from, should I create multiple sink connector for each of the topic or should I include them all in 1 connector ?
 2. If I use same connector for all the I am keeping below config to ingest data in s3.
 "flush.size": "2147483647"
 "rotate.interval.ms": "3600000"
 3. Data frequency is in GBs for all the topics, is the above config will be able to handle the load or should I try making some changes in config?

Comment: You can increase the max task count so that multiple threads will be able to read all the partitions of all the topics. However, if one topic fails to be read for any reason, then all tasks start failing, then no topics will be read. Therefore it's better to separate have separate connectors for fault tolerance. Data size doesn't really matter